# Divide different groups by reference group

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, group-by

I'm having so far this df: (not column `result`):

```
df <- data.frame(number = c(1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3),
                 value1 = c(5,7,6,9,3,5,6,3,4,5,5,6),
                 group = c("control", "Treated1", "Treated2", "Treated3","control", "Treated1", "Treated2", "Treated3","control", "Treated1", "Treated2", "Treated3"),
                 result = c(1,1.4,1.2,1.8,1.0,1.67,2,1,1,1.25,1,1.2))

   number value1    group result
1       1      5  control   1.00
2       1      7 Treated1   1.40
3       1      6 Treated2   1.20
4       1      9 Treated3   1.80
5       2      3  control   1.00
6       2      5 Treated1   1.67
7       2      6 Treated2   2.00
8       2      3 Treated3   1.00
9       3      4  control   1.00
10      3      5 Treated1   1.25
11      3      5 Treated2   1.00
12      3      6 Treated3   1.20
```

I want to group the data by number and also by group and then divide each subgroup of `group` with the `control` of the same `number`group, but I'm struggling to archieve this.
e.g.

```
Line1: 5/5 = 1.0
Line2: 7/5 = 1.40
Line3: 6/5 = 1.20
Line4: 9/5 = 1.80
Line5: 3/3 = 1.0
```

I tried to do something like that (which does not work obviously):

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
   group_by(number) %>%
   mutate(result = value1[group == contains("Treated")] / value1[group == control)
```

Do you have any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

You can index `value1` which has `group == "control"`, and divide all other `value1` with this value.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% group_by(number) %>% mutate(result = value1/value1[group == "control"])
```

Or you can `arrange` the `group` column, so that "control" will always be the `first` value.

```
df %>% group_by(number) %>% 
  arrange(number, group) %>% 
  mutate(result = value1/first(value1))
```

#### Output

```
# A tibble: 12 × 4
# Groups:   number [3]
   number value1 group    result
    <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>     <dbl>
 1      1      5 control    1   
 2      1      7 Treated1   1.4 
 3      1      6 Treated2   1.2 
 4      1      9 Treated3   1.8 
 5      2      3 control    1   
 6      2      5 Treated1   1.67
 7      2      6 Treated2   2   
 8      2      3 Treated3   1   
 9      3      4 control    1   
10      3      5 Treated1   1.25
11      3      5 Treated2   1.25
12      3      6 Treated3   1.5
```

Answer (score 1):

If your expectation is there should always be just one `"control"` per group, consider indexing by `[[which(group == "control")]]` rather than `[group == "control"]`. This is less succinct and likely a bit slower than @benson23's solution. But if `"control"` appears more than once in a group, `[[` will alert you by throwing an error.

For instance, say you forget to group your data by `number`. `[[` appropriately throws an error:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% mutate(result = value1/value1[[which(group == "control")]])
# Error in `mutate()`:
#   ℹ In argument: `result = value1/value1[[which(group == "control")]]`.
# Caused by error in `value1[[which(group == "control")]]`:
#   ! attempt to select more than one element in vectorIndex
```

whereas `[` silently returns incorrect output:

```r
df %>% mutate(result = value1/value1[group == "control"])
#    number value1    group   result
# 1       1      5  control 1.000000
# 2       1      7 Treated1 2.333333
# 3       1      6 Treated2 1.500000
# 4       1      9 Treated3 1.800000
# 5       2      3  control 1.000000
# 6       2      5 Treated1 1.250000
# 7       2      6 Treated2 1.200000
# 8       2      3 Treated3 1.000000
# 9       3      4  control 1.000000
# 10      3      5 Treated1 1.000000
# 11      3      5 Treated2 1.666667
# 12      3      6 Treated3 1.500000
```

This illustrates why it's often a good idea to use `[[` when exactly one value is expected.